# valid date format for mm/dd/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to use a regex for for both types of dates which is dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy

right now i am using this regex

```
/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/
```

which makes sure my dates always end up in doubledigits for day and double digits for month and 4 digits for year and that is what is required,

but any javascript expert can guide if i have two valid regex dates following the two formats i am trying to do.

i do not want my dates to end up in 99/99/9999 but at least like 31/12/3000 or 12/31/3000

so the ending date valid is the 3000 and not more than that

this is what i tried

```
/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/
```

i9 am not expert at regex but  this is what i was trying to do to make sure they enter date in the format it is required

Comment: I assume your date is in string format? Then I would just do str = yourDate.split("/") and check the length of str[0], str[1], str[2]. And if you want to make sure it's a number (and not something like aa/00/aaa) you could check that str[0] === +str[0] etc ...

Comment: *"for both types of dates"*: you mean you don't care which of the two formats it is?

Comment: It's by no means anywhere near perfect but you can try something like this `((?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:19[0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2})|(?:0[0-9]|1[0-2])\/(?:[0-2][0-9]|3[01])\/(?:19[0-9]{2}|20[0-9]{2}))`

Comment: @Buttered_Toast it means that i want two regex for both formats,and shuld be valid dates, not any strings etc etc, one regexs should check for dd/mm/yyyy and the other regex should check for dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: how do you know if your date is in d-m-y or m-d-y format? because it is important to check in JS the consistency of your date!

Comment: You talk about inputting your date, why not just use `<input type="date">` which automatically does this kind of check...

Comment: can't use date, not a requirement

Comment: @MisterJojo that check i will add in the data attribute of the class which format to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can test this way :

```js
const 
  rgxDte = /^\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}$/
, msgTxt =
   [ 'date is valid'
   , 'date doesn\'t respect regex' 
   , 'date year is > 3000'
   , 'date has invalid day / month value(s)'
   ];
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach( btn =>
  {
  const 
    inDateTxt = btn.closest('label').querySelector('input')
  , outMsg    = btn.closest('label').querySelector('output')
  , dte_DMY   = inDateTxt.placeholder === 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    ;
  inDateTxt.oninput =_=>
    {
    outMsg.textContent = ''
    }    
  btn.onclick =_=>
    {
    let msgIndx = rgxDte.test(inDateTxt.value) ? 0 : 1
      ;
    if (!msgIndx) // same as if (msgIndx===0)
      {
      let 
        [ DM, MD, year ] = inDateTxt.value.split('/').map(Number)
      , day      = dte_DMY ? DM : MD
      , month    = (dte_DMY ? MD : DM) -1   // month value is an index (first month indx is zero)
      , dateTest = new Date( year, month, day ) // work with adds,ex: if day > month number days it add days value and do month++
        ;
      if (year > 3000)
        msgIndx = 2;

      if (!msgIndx  && ( dateTest.getDate() !== day  ||  dateTest.getMonth() !== month )) 
        msgIndx = 3;
      }
    outMsg.classList.toggle('BAD', !!msgIndx)
    outMsg.textContent = msgTxt[msgIndx] 
    }
  })
```

```css
body {
  font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size   : 16px;
  margin      : 1rem;
}
label, input, output {
  display: block;
  }
input {
  padding    : .2rem .5rem;
  width      : 8rem;
  font-size  : 1.2rem ;
}
output {
  height : 2em;
  margin : .5rem 0 1rem 0;
  color  : green;
  }
output.BAD { color : red; }
```

```html
<label>
  dd/mm/yyyy : 
  <input type="text" id="inDMY" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
  <button>check</button>
  <output></output>
</label>

<label>
  mm/dd/yyyy : 
  <input type="text" id="inMDY" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
  <button>check</button>
  <output></output>
</label>
```

Comment: i checked the date `12/12/2022` and the code failed it, says date doesn't match regex.

Comment: @Roza fixed : it was a typo error in the regex string (`.` vs `,`)

Comment: here is the jsfiddle i have https://jsfiddle.net/05oe4hzn/

Comment: i was also making changes and i was quite close to the validation but only issue is i am missing the actual regex in both formats i am trying

Comment: its not like that, when you posted your answer, i already had worked offline to get an answer. I liked your code at least i learned something new, the way you descrbed it and thanks very much for that, understand that rehex can't help in all these but  i should atleast try, maybe not a regex but a function in front of the constants so at least the value passed should match what i was expecting